# Getting error Undefined offset: 1

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, error-handling

I know that this error has occurred a lot, however I have not been able to find another question on the site that lines up my my issue.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$handle = fopen('text document here', 'r');

if ($handle === false) {
die("ERROR");
}
$array = array();
$array = fgets($handle);

$handle = explode("\n", $array);

$foo = $handle;
$outA = array();
$outB = array();


foreach($foo as $value)
{
    list($x, $y) = explode(",",$value);
    $outA[] = $x;
    $outB[] = $y;
}

echo $outA[0];
echo $outB[0];
?>
```

I keep getting the error "Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\arraytest.php on line 20"

although I get the error I printed out the first two values from the array and they both seem to be correct, so I don't know exactly what is causing this.

--EDIT--

Here is the structure of my data I am importing:

12,13 
12,14
12,15
12,16
12,17
12,18
12,21
12,22
12,31

Comment: Are you actually using this `$handle = fopen('text document here', 'r');` as your code or giving it an actual filename? i.e. `$handle = fopen('file.txt', 'r');`

Comment: bad variable names. problematic!

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah I am actually importing a file. my structure is as follows:

12,13
12,14
12,15

etc, etc..

Comment: Can you show us the file and explain what exactly are you trying to capture? The issue is with `list()` but we can probably suggest a better way to do this.

Comment: @Haymaker I tested your code with comma seperated values as well as 10 words one underneath each other with no commas and only the first value gets printed with no errors, so it must be something in your `.txt` file. Edit your question with your actual file content.

Comment: Edited question for data structure.

Comment: @Haymaker I retested with your edited file structure and got no errors. It printed as `1213` only.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah, as I said, I was able to print out the first value from the two arrays, and I get the values I am looking for. I just don't understand why that error is thrown.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: I'm getting the Undefined Offset error with the OP's code and file.

Comment: @AmalMurali I am on paid hosting and not a local machine, so I couldn't replicate the problem.

Comment: @AmalMurali haha, well I don't feel as bad now knowing that I am not completely crazy :P

Comment: @Haymaker: Are you just trying to get values in first line and store it into two variables?

Comment: Bascially the ideal output would be that all the numbers in the left hand column would be in their own array and then the column on the right hand side would be in their own array as well. Key pairs, always.

Comment: @Haymaker Try using the `rb` switches instead of `r`, see if that gets rid of the error. Maybe your file was uploaded in binary format instead of text.

Comment: @Fred-ii- tried using both r ,rb, and rt to see if that would fix it. No luck...

Comment: @Haymaker I'm curious, are you using this in conjunction with a form by any chance? Another option would be to use `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE)` to hide Notices

Comment: @Fred-ii- Not a form for this instance, but I may have to keep in mind for any future occurrences with that

Comment: @Haymaker Ok, was just wondering. I noticed on another question that using it in a form could also be the cause of the error message. Glad you found a solution, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you're not actually looping through all the lines in the file.

```
$array = fgets($handle);
```

Now, `$array` variable will contain only the first line. Rest of the lines are ignored.

And, in your code, you have:

```
list($x, $y) = explode(",",$value);
```

which basically tries to assign the first array value to `$x` and second one to `$y`. There isn't a second item, so you'll get an `Undefined offset` error.

The solution would be to actually loop through the lines. I'd use a `while` loop as follows:

```
$handle = fopen('text document here', 'r');

if ($handle === false) {
die("ERROR");
}

while(!feof($handle))
{
    $value = fgets($handle);
    list($x, $y) = explode(",",$value);
    $outA[] = $x;
    $outB[] = $y;
}

echo $outA[0]."\n";
echo $outB[0];
```

Outputs:

```
12
13
```

The rest of the values are also correctly stored. You can verify this using `print_r($outA);`.

Comment: Code has been tested and works great! I noticed that the arrays were not fetching past the first row, but you already beat me to the fix. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Haymaker: Glad to have been of help!